# How can I serve my web app with Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm probably going to ask a huge noob question, one of the worst I've ever had asked here, but I'm lost as hell with Node/Express. I've only used Apache servers (typical WAMP/XAMP for testing purposes), so I have absolutely no idea on what I have to do to serve my web app.

My folder tree is the following:

- www

  - nodeserver.js
  - (more things)
  - Liteconomy (my web app)

    - js
    - css
    - plugins
    - templates
    - index.html
    - sublime_project

Pretty typical, huh? Well, I've been searching how to serve this app with a simple access like localhost:8080/Liteconomy, or localhost:8080/Liteconomy.html. After that, my angular routing would do the rest, but I just can't serve the app.

I've got this written in nodeserver.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});

app.get('/Liteconomy', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Liteconomy/index.html');
});
```

When I execute it and access to localhost:8080, I get the "Hello world", but when I go to localhost:8080/Liteconomy, I get the following plain text: "Liteconomy/index.html". If I try to access to the index resource directly, I get a "Cannot GET /Liteconomy/index.html" error.

I also tried using the static thingy, but didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here? I guess I'm just missing something very important.

Comment: "I get the following plain text: "Liteconomy/index.html". — Well yes. You sent plain text to the `send()` method, so that's what you get.

Comment: "I also tried using the static thingy, but didn't work either." — If you want to serve static files then "the static thingy" is what you should be using. We can't tell why it didn't work if you don't show us your attempts to use it.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that Node is not a web server. It is a way to run some JavaScript. You are attempting to write a web server in JS.

Comment: "After that, my angular routing would do the rest, but I just can't serve the app." — If you aren't wanting to do more then serve static files, then don't use Node.JS. That's like using an ultra customisable swiss army knife when you just need a standard power drill. Use Apache or Lightty or something that makes serving static files simple.

Comment: Look at `res.sendFile()` in the express docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following, it will resolve your issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(cookieParser());

// uncomment following if you want to access your app from /liteconomy
//app.use('/liteconomy', express.static(__dirname + '/Liteconomy', {index: "index.html"}));

//This will enable you to access it form '/'
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/Liteconomy', {index: "index.html"}));

// Rest of the stuff
```

Then if you will visit your URL that you set and port, you'll be able to access.

Using `express.static` is recommended way of serving static content.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It has 3 unresolved dependencies. I installed bodyParser and cookieParser but now it tells that it can't find the "logger" module.

Comment: @Zerok it was just a typo, As I copied it from my existing code and forgot removing logger, btw, my app uses `'morgan'`, I don't think it deserved a down vote, and body parser and cookie parser are standard good practices when working with node, in case in future if you intended to use query and customs routes using router, those will come in handy. Anyway, thanks for the input and i appreciate it! :) Keep up the good work my friend.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly :) gotta use it as base for my server, and try to learn and add changes from this.

Comment: @Zerok If you are interested in scaffolding a good express app, I have a step by step blog, you might find it helpful. [express.js scaffolding](https://oddcode.daveamit.com/2015/12/06/restful-api-with-express-js-and-mongodb-part-1/).

Answer (score -1):

You get a plain text answer because you actually ask to do it with the :

```
app.get('/Liteconomy', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Liteconomy/index.html');
});
```

If you want to send a simple html file like your index.html file, you should use the "sendfile " function :

```
app.get('/Liteconomy', function (req, res) {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/Liteconomy/index.html');
});
```

"__dirname" represents your root directory path and then you simply put your file path.

Hope that helps !

PS : by default express come with jade and ejs template support instead of just using html. I would advise you to take a look at one of them, it can be a great help to construct your application web pages.