# node how can My app find index.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Folder structure

- bin - www.js
- lib - jsFiles...
- models - jsFiles...
- node_modules -Folders and Files
- public - index.html
- route - jsFiles...
- index.js
- package.json

> I use Express, angular.js. Server starts at www.js and It calls
>   index.js. After that, When I type merely "localhost:3000" It shows me
>   public/index.html. I don't have route for '/' but It shows me
>   'public/index.html'. I can not understand this. Please let me know
>   about the process.

www.js

```
var debug = require('debug')('example-server');
var app = require(process.cwd()+'/index');

//listen at 3000 port
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);


var server = app.listen(app.get('port'),function()
{
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

index.js

```
var favicon      = require('serve-favicon');
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var logger       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
//Connection for DB
require('./lib/connection');
var employees    = require('./routes/employees');
var teams        = require('./routes/teams');
var app = express();

// Writing at routing table
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(employees);
app.use(teams);


// send 404 to errorhandler
app.use(function(err,req,res,next)
{
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
});

...
...
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I guess you want to understand: "Why index.html gets served when you go to /" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express.js the sequence in which you register your middleware makes a huge difference.

When express.js receives a request, it starts from top and executes registered middleware.

Middlewares are registered in express app using `app.use(middleware_goes_here)` this type of middleware gets executed no matter what the request url is on the other hand you can also register a middleware like `app.use('/url/path',middleware_goes_here)` in this case we are registering this middleware to '/url/path' so this middleware will only get executed when you visit '/url/path' (and non of the previous matching middleware serves the request without calling next() )

This `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));` line of code does the magic.

You can go [here (express.static ref)](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to know more about static content serving and routing.

Basically what happens is, we are configuring  `express.static` middleware to serve static content "as is" from "public" folder. So when you make any request and it matches a static content in public folder, then it will serve it otherwise `express.static` will call next middleware in sequence.

So in your case, the first middleware that actually server input request is `express.static` without any route filters, so it servers `index.html` even without a specifically defined route. If your `public` folder had file at `public/javascript/jquery.js` then following url will map to it `http://localhost:3000/javascript/jquery.js`

> NOTE: You do not have to specify "public" in the url, the way in which `express.static` is registered, it will server contents FROM "public" folder.

................

> UPDATE: How does default work in `express.static`?

By default, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));` this will take `index.html` as default document. If you want to set `index2.html` as your default document, you can do that by doing something like this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'),{index: 'index2.html'}));`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand most things but I am still wondering about how can myApp serve index.html. I just request localhost:3000 not localhost:3000/index.html. Has it any defualt setting about name 'index'? When I modify the name index.html -> index2.html It isn't serve index2.html , It responses 404.

Comment: You can refer this for a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649097/how-can-i-serve-my-web-app-with-node-express/35649993#35649993

Comment: Oh that link is so helpful for me. Thank you so much. you are my savior.

Answer (score 1):

Put a relative path to folder(one up in hierarchy).

```
var app = require('../index');
```

Comment: oh I mean, var app = require('../index'); in www.js file will call index.js but when I request like 'localhost:3000' It shows me 'public/index.html' file. Even I don't have route for '/'. I can not understand.